# bash script to run a second command with select output from first command as variable

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, lspci

I'd like to get the output of the second command with the 7 character PSI domain (00:01.0) as a variable.  How can I write a bash script to do this?

```
jeff@jeff-probook:/$ lspci | grep VGA
    00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev c5)
```

```
jeff@jeff-probook:/$ lspci -v -s 00:01.0
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev c5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Carrizo
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 231
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at d0800000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

This definitely isn't working:

```
user@host:~$ cat lspciVGA
#!/bin/bash

var1="$(lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D")"
var2="$(expr substr ${var1} 0 7)"
var3="$(sudo lspci -v -s ${var2})"
echo "$var3"
```

Output:

```
user@host:~$ bash lspciVGA
expr: syntax error
lspci: option requires an argument -- 's'
Usage: lspci []

Basic display modes:
-mm             Produce machine-readable output (single -m for an obsolete format)
-t              Show bus tree

Display options:
-v              Be verbose (-vv for very verbose)
-k              Show kernel drivers handling each device
-x              Show hex-dump of the standard part of the config space
-xxx            Show hex-dump of the whole config space (dangerous; root only)
-xxxx           Show hex-dump of the 4096-byte extended config space (root only)
-b              Bus-centric view (addresses and IRQ's as seen by the bus)
-D              Always show domain numbers

Resolving of device ID's to names:
-n              Show numeric ID's
-nn             Show both textual and numeric ID's (names & numbers)
-q              Query the PCI ID database for unknown ID's via DNS
-qq             As above, but re-query locally cached entries
-Q              Query the PCI ID database for all ID's via DNS

Selection of devices:
-s [[[[]:]]:][][.[]]   Show only devices in selected slots
-d []:[]                        Show only devices with specified ID's

Other options:
-i        Use specified ID database instead of /usr/share/misc/pci.ids.gz
-p        Look up kernel modules in a given file instead of default modules.pcimap
-M              Enable `bus mapping' mode (dangerous; root only)

PCI access options:
-A      Use the specified PCI access method (see `-A help' for a list)
-O =  Set PCI access parameter (see `-O help' for a list)
-G              Enable PCI access debugging
-H        Use direct hardware access ( = 1 or 2)
-F        Read PCI configuration dump from a given file
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928224/trying-to-retrieve-first-5-characters-from-string-in-bash-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem in the assignment of var2. It should read:

```
var2=$(expr substr "${var1}" 1 7)
```

the reason for the quotes is that *var1* has whitespaces that confuse substr, and the 0 -> 1 is because it starts counting from 1.

Also there are some problems with your quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$(lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D")
var2=$(expr substr "${var1}" 1 7)
var3=$(sudo lspci -v -s "${var2}")
echo "$var3"
```

Comment: It worked just updating quotes for second line (var2).  Why is that?  Can you only use quotes once per line?

Comment: if you set var1 to i.e. 'hello world' then the command would become `expr substr hello world 1 7` - resulting in error. With quotes 'hello world' is treated as a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
lspci | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)'
```

and

```
lspci -v -s 00:01.0 | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)'
```

- `^\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces at the start and `\K` discards the match, this is to tackle the second case where there are spaces at the start
- `\S+` matches any number of non-whitespace characters, this is our desired portion
- The zero width positive lookahead pattern, `(?=\s+VGA\s)`, ensures that the desired match is floowed by `VGA` after whitespaces after the desired portion.

---

To save the output in a variable, use command substitution (`$()`):

```
value=$(lspci | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)')
```

Similarly:

```
value=$(lspci -v -s 00:01.0 | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)')
```

Now you can get the value by `$value`.

---

**Example (on my system):**

```
$ lspci | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)'
00:02.0

$ lspci -v -s 00:02.0 | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)'
00:02.0
```

Comment: I like how you account for whitespace and view VGA a different way. This worked for me: `user@host:~$ cat lspciVGA2 var1=$(lspci | grep -Po '^\s*\K\S+(?=\s+VGA\s)') var2=$(lspci -v -s "${var1}") echo "$var2"`

Comment: @conman253 Great..